# Converting Bulk Text to Hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, bulk

I am using Excel 2010. I have a column (A), for example that has about 500 numbers, all different. The number in each cell is slightly different. I  want to turn them into hyperlinks in bulk(that's easy) if you have the same URL. The twist is that they all have different URLs BUT the URL are not that much different. They are the "same" URLs but the number in the cell is inserted at the end of the URL and that's a specific page.

EXAMPLE.

The first 3 rows (**A1, A2, A3**) are the numbers (**977, 981, 961**) 
The URLs would show as PleaseHelp.com/index=**977** , PleaseHelp.com/index=**981**, PleaseHelp.com/index=**961**

I want to put the hyperlink PleaseHelp.com/index="(**A1, A2, A3**)" and automatically insert what ever is in Row 1 and automatically insert the number and make it a hyperlink.

I know that I will have to use VBA to code but its tough.

Comment: @Jordan Chapman Where do I place that code and will that take care of all of them at once or will I have to go 1 by 1?

Answer (score 3):

A really easy way would be

`B1 = HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.something.com/index=",A1))`

or

```
B1 = HYPERLINK("http://something.com/index="&A1)
```

(thanks [Siphor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3276974/siphor))

then you could just fill that down.

Comment: There is a HYPERLINK() excel formula. So =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://www.something.com/index=",A1)) or the shorter =HYPERLINK("http://www.something.com/index="&A1) should work